# How to score 20 item Mini-IPIP?

Tags: ipip

I want to use the [20-item Mini-IPIP](https://discovermyprofile.com/miniIPIP/introduction.html) ([Donellan et al., 2006](https://ipip.ori.org/MiniIPIPKey.htm)) in a study. The scoring key [here](https://ipip.ori.org/MiniIPIPKey.htm) suggests that I should:

- Score each question from 1 to 5 (integers only)
- Make sure to reverse the scoring for the - keyed questions.
- Add up the scores to get a score out of 20 in each category.

How do I convert this to a score out of 100 for each?

It can't be as simple as multiplying by 5, since the linked website (where you can take the test) presents scores like 92%.

I couldn't find the scoring key in the original 2006 paper (this could be my idiocy) so I came here.